# Join a list of IDs in a string with another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I run into a problem that I have a hard time to figure it out. Hopefully you can help me.

I have a string called "TheOrderIDs" from different table/field, and this string (Varchar) contains the order IDs as this format "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7".

A regular query for multiple IDs would be:

```
Select * from tblOrder where OrderID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

But if I save the "TheOrderIDs" in a variable and put it in the query IN () statement, it will not work.

Any idea how to convert string of OrderIDs into a format that query IN () understand?

Thanks,

Comment: Why aren't `TheOrderIDs` rows in a table that is linked to your `tblOrder` via `OrderID`?

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#List

Comment: @TimSchmelter, it was a little design problem. I am just looking for the way to convert those IDs in rows/table or somehow to a type that query IN () clause recognize them as multiple IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have this type of design problems I do it like this:

```
Select * from tblOrder 
where ',' + REPLACE(@VarcharWithCommaSeparatedValues, ' ', '') + ',' LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), OrderID) + ',%'
```

Comment: Since OP seemingly does not need to `JOIN` based on these IDs you trick is neat.

Comment: Thank you, Nice Workaround!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use Dynamic SQL - Example:

```
use mydb;
go
declare  @sql  varchar (100)
declare  @vals varchar(100)
set @vals='(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)'
set @sql = 'Select * from tblOrder where OrderID IN' + @vals
exec (@sql)
```

I don't like this (at least because of performance) but it should work.